# Retrieve all data via void function

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing, cin

Been trying to find a way through this. I am new to C++ and creating a simple program to get the user data, validate and cout to the screen. What i'm trying to do is to have the one function use pointers to get the users input and display back to them. This may have been answered before but I haven't had much luck finding it.

So far i have the below code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void userData(int&);

int main(){
int a = 0;
int * kmpointer;   
int * dayspointer;

userData();

cout << "You ran " << userData(kmpointer) << endl;    
cout << "in " << userData(dayspointer) << "days!!" <<endl;

}

void userData(int& i){
cout << "Enter how Many Km's you ran:";

while (true)
{
    cin >> kmpointer;

    if ((cin) && (kmpointer >= 0) && (inputYear <= 100))
    break;

cin.clear();
cin.ignore( 100, '\n' );
cout << "That can't be right!\n";
cout << "Enter how Many Km's you ran:";
}

cout << "How many days in a row did you run?";
while (true)
{
    cin >> dayspointer;

    if ((cin) && (dayspointer >= 1) && (dayspointer <= 100))
    break;

cin.clear();
cin.ignore( 1000, '\n' );
cout << "Thats way to much!";
cout << "How many days in a row did you run? ";
}

}
```

Comment: What is your question? Your code is full of errors, Try solving them one by one ;-)

Comment: Sorry - trying to retrieve the users input from the function and use a pointer to display them to the screen. Im only new to c++ and slowly working my way through it.

Comment: `userData` takes a reference to one `int`, so send it an `int` like `userData(a)`, exdcept I suspect you want to send it all three ints. Which don't need to be pointers.

Answer (score 1):

> IMO, you should start with some reading about C++. You are missing some basic concepts and trying too complex exercises for your level.

**1**
function is not declared/defined.

**2**
`userData` is declared accepting a parameter, but used without.

**3**
The problem you face is related probably with what we call `scope`: A variable is only existing and visible within its scope (usually enclosed by `{` and `}`.

In your case, `kmpointer` and `dayspointer`are only visible within the `main` function and thus, you cannot use them in `userData`.

To solve that, I suggest you to pass those variables as parameters for `userData`.

**4**
Pointers, references, values: They are different. You are saving the user input as a pointer address, which is indeed problematic.

**General**

In general, your code is full of mistakes. Try a `Hello world!` and continue from there steps by steps.

Comment: moreover : "cin won't work with pointers how you expect it to work", or even "don't use raw pointers in C++, they are useful only in very special cases" and "learn about references"

Answer (score 0):

Focussing on the specific question you asked (though as observed you have other problems in your code), don't use pointers, use references.

Before we get to that this

```
cout << "You ran " << userData(kmpointer) << endl;
```

won't compile, since as you know `userData` is a void function, so applying `<<` to it makes no sense. It's void so there's nothing to stream.

You said you wanted to pass parameters into the function and let them be changed so do that. Then display the variables afterwards. (Not the "result" of a `void` function call).

Correctly getting the user input is a separate question which has been answered before.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void userData(int& i, int& j, int& k);

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    int kmpointer;
    int dayspointer;

    //Here we call our function, ONCE
    userData(a, kmpointer, dayspointer);

    //Here we display what values we now have
    //after calling the function, ONCE
    cout << "You ran " << kmpointer << endl;
    cout << "in " << dayspointer << " days!!" << endl;

}

//simplified to demonstrate changes to the reference parameters
void userData(int& i, int& j, int& k) {
    //Here we have three parameters which we refer to as i, j and k
    // They may have different names ousdie in the calling code
    //  but this function (scope) neither knows nor cares
    j = 42;
    k = 101;
}
```